# How do I convert an int16_t Core Data object into an int variable (and back)?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, uisegmentedcontrol

This is driving me nuts.

I've got a field in my Core Data model called "cardType" that is defined as an int16_t.

I want it to hold the setting for a UISegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex which is defined as an int. This particular UISegmentedControl is set for 4 segments, so an int16_t is overkill.

If I try to set

```
segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = [dataTable cardType];
```

I get an error "Incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'NSInteger' (aka 'int') from 'int16_t *' (aka 'short *')"

For fun, I put an asterisk in front of the method return, ie. *[dataTable cardType], but that obviously didn't work. I also did an (int *)dataTable.cardType, but that was a stupid try as well. The compiler liked it, but the runtime threw up all over it.

I also tried a bit of multistep code where I tried to move the value into a series of NSNumber and NSInteger operations, but none of those worked either.

Another thought I just had would be to convert the datatype to an NSString and use the string functions to convert it between text and integer, but that doesn't seem very elegant.

Seems like this should be something really simple and I'm just too numb to find it.

Comment: Did you autogenerate the `dataTable` class? And try `[[dataTable cardType] integerValue]`

Comment: Yes. For IntegerValue, I've tried to enter this, but it doesn't autotype that method, which means it's probably not available in the way I've implemented it. And if I force that messaging, I get "Bad receiver type 'int16_t *' (aka 'short *')"

Comment: Why do you have a `short *`? If you're using Core Data it should be an `NSNumber`

Comment: @property (nonatomic) int16_t *cardType;

Comment: Did you write that explicitly yourself?

Comment: The @property? No, that was auto generated by Core Data.

Comment: I just removed the pointer declaration to cardType that Core Data auto generated and everything works as I wanted it to work. What a headache that was! Thanks for your replies @Wain.

Answer (score 0):

Core Data autogenerated a pointer to an int for the @property instead of a plain int.

I changed:

```
@property (nonatomic) int16_t *cardType;
```

to

```
@property (nonatomic) int16_t cardType;
```

And everything is now working the way I wanted. Namely,

To save the segmentedControl

```
[dataTable setCardType:[cardTypePicker selectedSegmentIndex]];
```

To set the segmentedControl

```
cardTypePicker.selectedSegmentIndex = [dataTable cardType];
```

I don't know if this is an Xcode bug or not.